# Uninstall android application with out user interaction

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing android system application. Directly Uninstall another application without user interaction.
I have wrote peace of code ,

```
private void UninsallApp() {
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"com.example.shortcutcreation");
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}
```

but before uninstall app dialog box is coming like 
[image]

Could you please help me...

Comment: `Directly Uninstall another application without user interaction.` do you expect to be able to do that without the user's consent?

Comment: yes @Nikola, I am doing android system administrate application.

Comment: You know that the entire point of this monit is to prevent such activities as the one you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This app is only for display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this question. 
I have cracked code AOSP framework level(android.content.pm) and signed as a ploatform apk ...
Finally app is silently uninstalling...

or

String cmd = "sh /system/bin/pm uninstall " + packageName;

```
    try {Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(cmd+"\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        su.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```